# Laravel calling @show instead of @destroy

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a problem with my routes in Laravel (v. 4.2)..

View:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin.users.destroy', $user->user_id]]) }}
      <td><button type="submit" style="...">Delete</button></td>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'App\Controllers\Admin\UserIndexController');
```

Controller:

```
public function show() {
    echo "show";
}

public function destroy() {
    echo 'destroy';
}
```

When the button is clicked though it always prints out "show". Why is this?

Comment: Your button isn't actually doing anything. It would need to be a submit button, or use javascript to use it to submit the form.

Comment: @aynber Still the same

Comment: Open up your browser console and watch the Network tab as you press the button. What method is the request using?

Comment: Can you ensure that this delete form isn't actually wrapped in a larger show form?

Comment: @yes, there is no other form

Comment: @anyber 
**Status:** 200
**Method:** GET
**File:** ...?_method=DELETE&_token=TuYmcW90oUtPUIygqyb9mSEQo1AvEeQ4YHl5c4Zd
**Domain:** localhost

Localhost shouldn't be the issue, right?

Comment: Makes me think.. I have XAMPP installed, does it allow DELETE and PUT methods by default or it has to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms cannot make `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` requests so you need to spoof it with Laravel.

Add this to your form...

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

I believe this generally isn't an issue with newer versions of Laravel since the Form builder has been removed from the core and is now being managed by `LaravelCollective` which will handle adding this input automatically.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form

Comment: This is added automatically by laravel (when inspecting the element in a browser) this is not the problem then.. From the network tab in my browser im still getting GET method instead of DELETE

Comment: Yeah that will only ever be GET or POST.  Laravel should be reading the hidden input, if it's there, and determining what kind of request it is based off that.

Comment: Yes. It does not however.

Comment: I just set this up in 4.2 with exactly your code.  The only thing I did that you aren't showing which I assume you did anyway was update the classmap to load the controller in the admin directory.  Seems to work fine for me even without adding the hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Edited Answer:

```
Routes.php

Route::resource('admin/users', 'UserIndexController');

{{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['admin.users.destroy', $user->user_id]]) }}
      <td><button type="submit" style="...">Delete</button></td>
{{ Form::close() }}

public function show() {
        echo "show";
    }

    public function destroy() {
        echo 'destroy';
    }
```

I am getting "destroy" as output.

Comment: I added the type attribute but it still prints out "show"